# Unable to call function on object in vector of objects

Tags: c++, vector

I have this class:

```
class Line
{
public:
   Line() {}
   Line(const Line& l) {clone_(l);}
   Line& operator=(const Line& l) { if (&l == this) return *this; riadok_.clear(); clone_(l); return *this;}
   void print() {for (auto&& x: riadok_) {x->print(); }}
   void add(valptr p) {riadok_.push_back(std::move(p));}
   void clear() {riadok_.clear();}
private:
   void clone_(const Line& l) {for (auto&& x: riadok_) riadok_.push_back(x->clone());}
   std::vector<valptr> riadok_;
};
```

And when I try to do this:

```
vector<Line> v;
Line l;
//insert things into the line
v.push_back(l);
v[0].print();
```

nothing happens. Console stays blank instead of showing contents of line `l`. What's wrong?

Comment: vector<Line> v;

Comment: Please show us how you "insert things into the line". Preferably please try to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and show us. And if you haven't done it yet, then please [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: l.add(make_unique<IntVal>(123));

Comment: what should it print? there are no contents

Comment: But I do recommend you to look at the `clone_` function. First of all, do you really need it (considering [the rule of zero](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three#Rule_of_zero))? Secondly, where do you copy ***from***?

Answer (score 0):

Everything is ok, except that the print in the Line needs some elements.
Add something to your Line with v[0].add(smth) and it should be ok.